# Cannot unmount useRef eventListener in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a drag and drop upload div. I am following a reference [link](https://medium.com/@650egor/simple-drag-and-drop-file-upload-in-react-2cb409d88929) that demonstrated removeEventListener in a class component unmounting phase.

Why can't I remove the event listener on unmounting phase with functional components? It seems like the ide is also not recognizing the `removeEventListener` function. What did I do wrong?

Do I actually have to removeEventListener, as it seems like the component did not unmount in the whole lifecycle?

```
const dropRef = useRef(null);

const handleDrag = (e) => {
    console.log("Drag Over detected!");
};

const handleDrop = (e) => {
    console.log("Drop detected!");
};

useEffect(() => {
    const div = dropRef.current;
    div.addEventListener("dragover", handleDrag);
    div.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);

    return () => {
      div.removeEventListener("dragover", handleDrag);
      div.removeEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
    };
  }, []);
```

```
<div className="uploadBox" ref={dropRef}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components:

you are not passing any dependency to `useEffect` which means, your `useEffect` only runs once (at the time of page render).

You to run it, you need to define the dependencies when this `useEffect` run,
in your case, passing div as a dependency should work.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const div = dropRef.current;
    div.addEventListener("dragover", handleDrag);
    div.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);

    return () => {
      div.removeEventListener("dragover", handleDrag);
      div.removeEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
    };
  }, [div]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare a static listener.
const eventListeners = useRef();

// now let's create our scroll Handler
const scrollHandler = useCallback(() => {...},[]);

useEffect(() => {
   // Here will be removing the static listener and then updated it for 
   // our new one since the first time will be empty it won't do anything.
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', eventListeners.current, true);

    // Then will set our current scroll handler to our static listener
    eventListeners.current = scrollHandler;

    // Here will be adding the static listener so we can keep the reference
    // and remove it later on
    window.addEventListener('scroll', eventListeners.current, true);
},[scrollHandler]);
```